# How can I realize this animation using TimelineMax and ScrollMagic plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm not very good at JavaScript, but I need to do this animation to get the job done.

It is necessary to implement such an animation as [on this website](https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/HX9954_53/sonicare-diamondclean-smart-sonic-electric-toothbrush-with-app). Look at the [blue block](https://prnt.sc/h7ytco) "What makes this the world's" with toothbrush and mobile. To implement it, the author uses plugins [TimelineMax](https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineMax) and [scrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/).

I managed to fix the block with the scroll, but I do not know what to do next..
How do I do scrolling for a #slider block ?

Link to [Codepan](https://codepen.io/Richswitch/pen/QOGYeL).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// scrollmagic

(function($) {

    var wh = window.innerHeight,
        $zone = $('#owlZone'),
        $slider = $('#slider'),
        $itemOne = $('#itemOne'),
        $itemTwo = $('#itemTwo'),
        $itemThree = $('#itemThree');
    var ScreenHeight = $(window).height();
    
    var ctrl = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
        globalSceneOptions: {
            triggerHook: 0,
            tweenChanges: true,
            duration: ScreenHeight
        }
    });
//create scene
     $("#owlZone").each(function(index){

            new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: this
            })
                .setPin(this)
                .addTo(ctrl);
    });

// animate phone
    var SMController1 = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    // var tlm = new TimelineMax();
    // tlm.fromTo('#itemOne', 1, {x:0, y:0}, { x:0,  y:0    })
    //    .fromTo('#itemTwo', 2, {x:"0", y:0},   { x:0,  y:0  })
    //    .fromTo('#itemThree', 5, {x:0, y:0}, { x:0,  y:0    })

       // .to('.toushbrush-slider', 3, {opacity:0});
       // .fromTo('#slider', 2, {}, {});
       // .to('#slider', 2, {rotation:90, left:'50%'});

    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                        triggerElement: "#owlZone",
                        duration: 1500, 
                        triggerHook: 0.2
    })
    // .setTween(tlm)
    .addIndicators()
    .setPin('#slider')
    .addTo(SMController1);


}) (jQuery);
 

});
```

```css
.section-block-three {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #02050b 0, #0f204b 50%, #1c3b8b 100%);
  background-color: #1c3b8b;
  padding: 150px 0 100px;
  position: relative; 
  }

.mob-app__head h4 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "centrale_sans_light";
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300; 
  }

.mob-app__head p {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px; 
  }

.mob-app__content p {
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px; 
  }

.mob-app__image {
  background-color: lime;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 135px;
  height: 549px; 
  }

.mob-app__store {
  margin-top: 100px; }
  .mob-app__store .app-store, .mob-app__store .google-play {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 44px;
    display: inline-block; 
    }
  .mob-app__store .app-store {
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    }
  .mob-app__store .google-play {
    background-color: purple; 
    }

.toushbrush-slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 60px; 
  }

.toushbrush-slider__images {
  position: relative;
  }
  .toushbrush-slider__images .images__image-one, .toushbrush-slider__images .images__image-two, .toushbrush-slider__images .images__image-three {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 175px;
    height: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
  .toushbrush-slider__images .images__image-one {
    background-color: red; 
    }
  .toushbrush-slider__images .images__image-two {
    background-color: green; 
    }
  .toushbrush-slider__images .images__image-three {
    background-color: yellow;
    }
  .toushbrush-slider__images .images__content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 50px 0 0 20px;
    }
    .toushbrush-slider__images .images__content p {
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-size: 16px; 
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section-block-three" id="owlZone">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
     <div class="mob-app__head">
      <h4>this is text<span></span></h4>
      <p><span>this is text</span> this is text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="mob-app__content">
      <p>this is text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="mob-app__store">
      <a href="#" class="app-store" alt="App Store"></a>
      <a href="#" class="google-play" alt="Google Play"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
     <div class="mob-app__image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="toushbrush-slider" id="slider">
      <div class="toushbrush-slider__images" id="itemOne">
       <div class="images__image-one"></div>
       <div class="images__content">
        <p>this is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is text</p>
       </div>
      </div>
       <div class="toushbrush-slider__images" id="itemTwo">
      <div class="images__image-two"></div>
      <div class="images__content">
       <p>this is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is text</p>
      </div>
     </div>
       <div class="toushbrush-slider__images" id="itemThree">
      <div class="images__image-three"></div>
      <div class="images__content">
       <p>this is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is textthis is text</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a few scroll plugins but always had hard times in terms of performance on major browsers, from IE to Safari.

The best approach I found was to bind an event handler to scroll, see 
[.scroll()](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

```
$( "#target" ).scroll(function() {
  globalScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

where I update a global variable to the last position, and then to install another timeout handler:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // set your object properties according to last scroll position
    // $('someobject').animate(...);
}, 200 /* experiment with timeout value for performance in all browsers */)
```

This helps a lot because the actual processing is done when the main thread is free and also avoids potential slow behavior by not performing rendering for each scroll event value - which the user might not even see. Performance penalties always come with plugins that are designed to work with many generic scenarios, therefore by learning to tailor your code for your specific needs will pay off big time.

I know I might get some downvotes but here I go: You should try as much as possible to first understand Javascript and how your code works, because you will run into trouble sooner or later. Having someone implement this for you here will unfortunately only help until your client has a small complaint.